# AJAX open link without page reload and PHP get variable

Tags: php

page.php

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Set trigger and container variables
    var trigger = $('.a'),
        container = $('#content');

    // Fire on click
    trigger.on('click', function(){
      // Set $this for re-use. Set target from data attribute
      var $this = $(this),
        target = $this.data('target');       

      // Load target page into container
      container.load(target +  ".php?id=<?php echo $_POST['id']?>");

      // Stop normal link behavior
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>


 <nav id="nav">
      <ul>
          <form method="post">
            <input name="id" value="12">
          </form>
        <li><a id="home" class="a" href="#" data-target="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="about" class="a" href="#" data-target="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content">

    <style>
    #home{display:none;}  
    </style>

    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>This is the home page</p>
    <h3>
    </h3>    
</div>
```

about.php

```
<h1>about</h1>
```

home.php

```
<h1>home</h1>
```

Script AJAX work good , without load it can open content infinity but problem is Row's number.
PHP
When i try to send ID on other content by POST method, or something it will not work.

Comment: Post your ajax code. And your row number is `id` ?

Comment: full code is here, i just want identify post

Comment: We can't help if you don't show how is your ajax script. BTW check in your console browser how you're sending your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. Assuming you are trying to send the "id" as a get parameter via AJAX and loading content in some div/section.

1. $_POST should be replaced with $_REQUEST ideally and surrounded by "isset".
2. put an action on the form.  put name and ID on the form values. Such as

   ```
   <input name="id" name="id" value="12">
   ```

Comment: same, not fixed :(

Comment: @Fsociety what is the output? Can you please expand?

Comment: nothing, when i try to write in about page <?php echo $_GET['id]?>
it is clear...

Comment: you are doing a "POST" in your form. So why would you do? $_GET['id]? As I said above do $_REQUEST

Comment: i made already but it dont work :( :( u sure i have mistake in my code?

Comment: does the page actually reload? You are doing an AJAX which means the PHP part of the page is only executed once on the server. If this is a singlepage app then you cannot do this via PHP and will need jquery.

Comment: im tired, do you have skype?